# How can I wrap form content in bootstrap divs?

Tags: theming, nodes, forms

I am fairly new to Drupal and I want to change the "add article" form a bit. Currently I have the following displayed:

[image]

I want to wrap these `<input>` fields in a few `<div>` so that I can apply bootstrap to it. I don't exactly how to do this, so I tried to alter the `.twig` files that are being called. For example `MY_THEME/templates/form/input.html.twig`. However all I can see is an `<input>` calling `{{ children }}`

[image]

If I place this in a div, it just wraps the whole form in this div. Is there a way to place the individual `<input>` fields in separate divs so that I can apply bootstrap to it?

Comment: Do you have twig debug turned on?  If you do, you can look at the source to see which templates are being called. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Comment: Yes I have turned debugging. I can see what is being called. But can't really seem to figure out where to put the divs

Answer (score 0):

The way you are suggesting works fine. (I just tested it). Try to clear your cache and hard refresh the page. If you do:

```
<div class="my_custom_class"><input{{ attributes }} />{{ children }}</div>
```

you will have your form inputs wrapped in that div.

The other options is to use the form-element.html.twig or you can use the `hook_form_alter` and add prefix and suffix to your fields.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Also, I noticed my changes are applied to ALL forms on my site. I also have a login form which seems to be affected by these changes. Is there a way to only edit a specific form?

Comment: If you want to change your twig file and apply it to specific elements you need to specify the name of the file according to your form. Have a look at this post https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237461/how-do-i-write-a-template-file-for-a-specific-input-field. If you go with the hook_form_alter option, you just need to check the form_id and apply prefix and suffix only to the fields of the specific form.